# Implement dynamic query string from forms to handle multiple queries

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented an endpoint in the backend that accepts multiple params depending on the search parameters:

e.g `/api/transaction_report/?year=2020&month=5&subcounty=2`

I have the form that has the filter parameters as inputs. How do I dynamically create a query string depending on different search filter combinations in the `onFilterTransactions()` function?

```
onFilterTrasactions() {

  const params = [];
  const dateFrom = this.dateFilterForm.get('fromDate').value
  const dateTo = this.dateFilterForm.get('toDate').value;
  const year = this.dateFilterForm.get('year').value;
  const month = this.dateFilterForm.get('month').value;
  const subcounty = this.dateFilterForm.get('subcounty').value;
  const ward = this.dateFilterForm.get('ward').value;
  const licenseCategoryCode = this.dateFilterForm.get('licenseCategoryCode').value;

  const formItems = [ dateFrom, dateTo, year, month, subcounty, ward, licenseCategoryCode ];

  for (const item of formItems) {

    if (item != null) {
      params.push(item);
    }


  }
  console.log(dateFrom)
  // console.log(this.dateFilterForm.value);


}
```

**Form Controls** 
For example one would only want to filter by month, therefore, the rest of the form values will end up being `null`.

```
this.dateFilterForm = new FormGroup({
  fromDate: new FormControl(),
  toDate: new FormControl(),
  year: new FormControl(),
  month: new FormControl(),
  subcounty: new FormControl(),
  ward: new FormControl(),
  licenseCategoryCode: new FormControl(),

});
```

**Fillter Screenshot**

[image]

**Search Service**

```
  getAllFilteredTransactions(query) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/transactions/filter_report/?${query}=`, {
      headers: this.headers
    });
  }
```

Comment: So you want to build your `query` string like `fromDate=...&toDate=...&year=...` and so on?

Comment: @VRoxa Yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this in two steps.

First, build a parameter list as a *key-value pair array*.

```
type KeyValue<T> = [string, T];

const getKVPairs = (form: any, ...keys: string[]): KeyValue<any>[] =>
    keys.map(key => {
        const value = form.get(key).value;
        return [ key, value ];
    });
```

Basically, it builds the collection of pairs with a key and a value extracted from the form itself.

You can filter this collection afterwards

```
// Parameter list
const keys = ['fromDate', 'toDate', 'year'];
const kvs = getKVPairs(form, ...keys);

// Check for value truthiness
const filtered = kvs.filter(([, value]) => !!value);
```

Then, time for build the query based on the collection on pairs.

```
const buildQuery = (...params: KeyValue<any>[]) => {
    const concat = (([key, value]): KeyValue<any>) =>
        `${key}=${value}`;

    // Creates the string list like
    // [ key=value , key=value ]
    const fields = params.map(concat);
    // Then joins with an '&' in between
    return fields.join('&');
}
```

I think it deserves to be a service itself which could be injected as a dependency on the component.
But, the functional way of make usage of this would be

```
const keys = ['fromDate', 'toDate', 'year'];
const kvs = getKVPairs(form, ...keys);
const filtered = kvs.filter(([, value]) => !!value);
const query = buildQuery(...filtered);

console.log(query); // fromDate=1&toDate=1&year=1
```

Supposing all values are `1`, for example.

**EDIT:**

The filter could be something more complex. I just offer a really short way... However, this could be any function like

```
const filter = (pairs: KeyValue<any>[], condition: (pair: KeyValue<any>) => boolean) =>
    pairs.filter(condition);
```

To make it flexible in case of having a service.

Moreover, the service would be like

```
@Injectable({...})
export class QueryBuilder {

    constructor(/* dependencies if needed */) {  }

    public build = (form: any, condition: (pair: KeyValue<any>) => boolean, ...keys: string[]) => {
        const kvs = this.getKVPairs(form, ...keys);
        const filtered = kvs.filter(condition);
        return this.buildQuery(...filtered);
    }

    private getKVPairs = (form: any, ...keys: string[]): KeyValue<any>[] =>
        keys.map(key => {
            const value = form.get(key).value;
            return [ key, value ];
        });

    private buildQuery = (...params: KeyValue<any>[]) => {
        const concat = (([key, value]): KeyValue<any>) =>
            `${key}=${value}`;

        const fields = params.map(concat);
        return fields.join('&');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.